# Light switch setup for bedroom

Tags: switches, high-voltage, light

on my bedroom I want to put two 220V lights on the side of my bed, and I want to control them with 3 switches:

the main switch is beside the door, and will commute both lights on and off.
two secondary switches, one under each light beside the bed, that will control only the light over it.

so, the main switch will turn on/off both lights.
the switch on the right side will control the right light.
the switch on the left side will control the left light.

There is a way to implement this configuration?

Comment: You can also try this one on diy.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this would be to use impulse relays for the two lamps. The exact configuration will depend on the desired behaviour:

The description

> the main switch will turn on/off both lights

is too imprecise. What should happen when only one of two lights are on when the main switch is pressed? Should there be any priority / override functionality for some switches? etc.

Comment: That is a nice question! I have thinked about it, and I want that if one light is on, and the main switch is pressed, both lights must go off